US Municipal bond (tax exempt) AAA benchmark curve - Reuters (or Bloomberg)
I want to mark a tax exempt AA muni bond using Reuters terminal, but the MMD AAA benchmark is not available, details:
MSRB historical trade spread on MMD AAA are published on reuters

but in the bond calculator I can only see current date MMD AAA benchmark

whenever I change to a historical date my MMD AAA benchmark curve disappears:

LSEG support said the curve has been discontinued and I should not be seeing it in the bond calculator, which seems weird to me, what curve should I use to mark tax exempt municipal bonds?
